# mikuso hub-014 is not work in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu-22.04

USB Hub 3.0 **MIKUSO HUB-014 USB Hub 4 Port 3 USB 2.0 + 1 USB 3.0**
I have a problem to use USB extension hub  mikuso hub-014 is not work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.